# Mysql sort data alternatively

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big table where data are structured like this

```
My table car
id_car | Site_car     | descr_car
-----------------------------------
1      | onesite      | onedesc
2      | twosite      | twodesc
3      | twosite      | onedesc
4      | onesite      | onedesc
5      | twosite      | twodesc
6      | onesite      | onedesc
7      | treesite     | onedesc
8      | treesite     | onedesc
```

I want to be able  to display the column site_car randomly but with onesite first twosite second and threesite third each 15 time or more

what I want to display

```
id_car | Site_car     | descr_car
-----------------------------------
4      | onesite      | onedesc
3      | twosite      | twodesc
7      | treesite     | onedesc
1      | onesite      | onedesc
2      | twosite      | twodesc
6      | treesite     | onedesc
```

Do you guys have idea?

Thx

Comment: not sure you can do that in SQL, unless someone has more arcane knowledge than me. Might be something you can do in an application layer. SQL doesn't really do "random" ordering AFAIK, and your second constraint is not really feasible either.

Comment: In the data set 3 is onedesc. But in the result 3 is two desc - but there was no mention of displaying the descr_car column randomly, so this makes not a lot of sense.

Comment: And treesite and threesite are not the same thing.

Comment: I think you would need session variables to do this.

Comment: I cannot fathom why this question would be downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky in MySQL.  The idea is to enumerate the rows and then order by that enumeration:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             (@rn := if(@sc = site_car, @rn + 1,
                        if(@sc := site_car, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select c.*
            from car c
            order by site_car, id_car
           ) c cross join
           (select @sc := -1, @rn := 0) params
     ) c
order by rn, field(site_car, 'onesite', 'twosite', 'threesite');
```

By the way this is much simpler in MySQL 8+:

```
select c.*
from car c
order by row_number() over (partition by site_car order by id_car),
         field(site_car, 'onesite', 'twosite', 'threesite');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
SET @Fno:= 999
SET @Sno:= 9999
SET @Tno:= 99999
SELECT   id_car, Site_car , descr_car from 
(SELECT  
@row_number:=CASE
    WHEN Site_car = 'onesite' THEN @Fno + 1
    WHEN Site_car = 'twosite' THEN @Sno + 1 
    ELSE @Tno+1 
END AS num,* from car) order by num
```